# Kinect 2 USB controller Matlab

Tags: matlab, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I am getting problem in configuration of Kinect sensor v2 in Matlab.

My Laptop have USB port 3.0, windows 8.1 and I have all necessary drivers required for Kinect in windows. When I connect Kinect with Laptop and check **"Kinect Configuration Verifier"** then I am getting following results.

[image]

Although it is not showing a green tic on USB Controller but when I run **Kinect Studio** or any other sample available in Microsoft SDK, it is running successfully.

But when I started work in Matlab R2015b then it started to give problem. I install required package of Kinect support for Matlab and then type this command, **imaqhwinfo('kinect')** it is not giving devices list. If no sensors are found then I can not proceed.
[image]

Till now I did not found any help.
Can anyone please guide me what is possible problem in this case and how should I proceed with this in Matlab?

Comment: Any details available what's wrong with the USB controller? I would expect some details when you click on the circle on the right side.

Comment: @Daniel It says that an Unknown USB controller 3.0 is detected. More info is available in this screen shot.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/so3ludcf0q1r06y/AABrSWiRW12FMgahiuRZoZFka?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion your Matalb Version might be the Problem. The Kinect V2 Support is quiet new and starts at R2016a.

Comment: Maybe this is an alternative http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53439-kinect-2-interface-for-matlab

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53439-kinect-2-interface-for-matlab.

There are C++ wrapper functions for the Microsoft Kinect 2, using Microsoft SDK.